# Adrenochrome artificial synthesis

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

Everyone has heard about [Adrenochrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenochrome) and its supposed ability to be [youth serum](https://scarenormal.com/the-elites-super-drug-adrenochrome/). Usual story goes that pure Adrenochrome could be only obtained by [child sacrifice](https://steverotter.com/adrenochrome-in-hollywood-and-politics/), i.e. by torturing kids (younger than 9 years) to raise their adrenaline levels, and then killing them. To facilitate this, shadowy elite has whole network of associates who procure children for them ( think [Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Epstein) multiplied by 100) .

I need someone with chemical knowledge to confirm or reject premise of this story - i.e. that sufficiently pure Adrenochrome cannot be synthesized artificially, thus avoiding the hassle of kidnapping and killing children. After all, even if we imagine "elites" to be entirely psychopathic and without conscience, they would still choose "easier" and cheaper route if possible. Of course, if artificial synthesis is possible, any idea why would not be used is highly appreciated.

Comment: "Everyone has heard about Adrenochrome ". No.

Comment: @L.Dutch You should visit more conspiracy sites :P

Comment: Adrenochrome (3-Hydroxy-1-methyl-2,3-dihydro-1H-indole-5,6-dione) is relatively easy to to synthesize. It is not manufactured because it has no applications, that is, nobody wants to buy it because it is useless. Its chemical derivative [carbazochrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbazochrome) *has* some limited utility as a haemostatic (= toxivenol) and can be bought [from a number of manufacturers](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Carbazochrome#section=Chemical-Vendors).

Comment: If you need an excuse for why some characters in your story  are supposedly evil (they are scrificing children and all that...) then take the lectures of Robert Sapolsky on neuroscience and learn where evil is born, they are 40 minutes to 1 hour and half video lectures, totalling around 35 hours of education. In short, no one needs a reason to be evil, it doesn't have to be justified, evolution doesn't work with reason, it works with randomness, and sometimes random evil prospers and survives even if it brings no good, simply because there's no cost to maintain it and no reason to lose it.

Comment: it also has a lot of explanations for free will, conscience and self control as well as educative content on trauma, memory and brain adaptations, all good stuff for any worldbuilder that wants to write intriguing and realistic stories

Comment: @AlexP Thanks, if you write an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: if you're building a world where the bogus claim "adenochrome is a youth serum" is true, then you can throw any existing chemistry overboard, anyway without needing any reasoning based in real world chemistry. (when in doubt, just call it "the _real_ adenochrome, not the fake news one that mainstream round-earth media wants you to believe to distract you from atlantis being ruled by lizard people")

Comment: @RPGlife Well, I need whole organization that is doing something evil, and it is hard to justify it with randomness if it is evolutionary counter-productive (i.e. you are doing something that could get you imprisoned or even executed, with no apparent reason). If someone could produce Adrenochrome without hassle artificially, it would be evolutionary easier to go with that route.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I'm not planning to build entire world, I'm exploring idea of using already existing mythos (with some original ideas, of course) . And would not like to build onto something that is not at least remotely scientific.

Comment: *"If someone could produce Adrenochrome without hassle":* that is not the point. The point is adrenochrome (a.k.a. pink adrenaline) is oxidized adrenaline. It serves no purpose. It is a waste product. Giving it to a human induces psychotic reactions. There was even a medical hypothesis that it was actively harmful, producing schizophrenia. (This proved false, because schizophrenics have as little adrenochrome in their bodies as non-schizophrenics.) So the first thing the organization should do is to show that adrenochrome has some useful effects.

Comment: @AlexP Well, you said it yourself, it has certain effects on human, even if they are harmful. Showing what effects certain substance has on humans is arduous process, sometime they could be both adverse and beneficial, depending on circumstances. But production is far more straightforward matter - either you could produce it or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a minute on wikipedia:

[Epinephrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epinephrine_(medication)#History):

> Adrenaline was first synthesized in the laboratory by Friedrich Stolz and Henry Drysdale Dakin, independently, in 1904.

[Adrenochrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrenochrome#Chemistry):

> The oxidation reaction that converts adrenaline into adrenochrome occurs both in vivo and in vitro. In vitro, silver oxide (Ag2O) is used.

The references associated with both quotes are not available online. The latter is associated with a paper from 1946, so synethesis of adrenochome has clearly been possible for over 70 years. I can't get any useful figures for how much epinephrine is synthesized per year, but around two million prescriptions for epinephrine-containing products are [made each year in the US](https://clincalc.com/DrugStats/Drugs/Epinephrine). It isn't clear if this includes in-hospital use. There doesn't appear to be a shortage of the chemical itself, anyway.

So. It is well within the abilities of the modern pharmaceutical industry to generate generous quantities of this useless, toxic waste product. It doesn't, because that would be pointless.

> thus avoiding the hassle of kidnapping and killing children

It the old [blood libel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_libel) rolled out again. It needs the shock value of dead and missing children to work. There's no truth behind it. If you need some technobabble excuse to drive your plot, call it whatever you like. I wouldn't want to associate myself or my work with q-anon, but you do you.

Comment: Thanks, good enough answer.